# Can this regex be further optimized?

Tags: java, regex, optimization, scala

I wrote this regex to parse entries from srt files.

```
(?s)^\d++\s{1,2}(.{12}) --> (.{12})\s{1,2}(.+)\r?$
```

I don't know if it matters, but this is done using Scala programming language (Java Engine, but literal strings so that I don't have to double the backslashes).

The `s{1,2}` is used because some files will only have line breaks `\n` and others will have line breaks and carriage returns `\n\r`
The first `(?s)` enables `DOTALL` mode so that the third capturing group can also match line breaks.

My program basically breaks a srt file using `\n\r?\n` as a delimiter and use Scala nice pattern matching feature to read each entry for further processing:

```
val EntryRegex = """(?s)^\d++\s{1,2}(.{12}) --> (.{12})\s{1,2}(.+)\r?$""".r

def apply(string: String): Entry = string match {
  case EntryRegex(start, end, text) => Entry(0, timeFormat.parse(start),
    timeFormat.parse(end), text);
}
```

Sample entries:

One line:

```
1073
01:46:43,024 --> 01:46:45,015
I am your father.
```

Two Lines:

```
160
00:20:16,400 --> 00:20:19,312
<i>Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi.
You're my only hope.</i>
```

The thing is, the profiler shows me that this parsing method is by far the most time consuming operation in my application (which does intensive time math and can even reencode the file several times faster than what it takes to read and parse the entries).

So any regex wizards can help me optimize it? Or maybe I should sacrifice regex / pattern matching succinctness and try an old school `java.util.Scanner` approach?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not optimistic, but here are two things to try:

1. you could do is move the `(?s)` to just before you need it.
2. remove the \r?$ and use a greedy `.++` for the text `.+`

   ^\d++\s{1,2}(.{12}) --> (.{12})\s{1,2}(?s)(.++)$

To really get good performance, I would refactor the code and regex to use `findAllIn`. The current code is doing a regex for every `Entry` in your file. I imagine the single `findAllIn` regex would perform better...But maybe not...

Comment: I was so sure that possessive quantifier wouldn't work :D... Well, it did, and further improved the average time about 5% (hard to measure, but I'm sure it is faster, average is about 25ms). About that findAllin, do you know if its Iterators are lazy or strict? I don't want to read the entire file into memory since they can be really huge.

Comment: How are you splitting the file now? Are you not reading it into memory by putting it into a List? Anyway, a good regex engine should be able to match more efficiently than splitting and matching individually.

Comment: I'm using a Scala strick to hide a java Scanner (\n\r?\n delimiter) behind a Lazy Iterator. Then I map each entry to a object, process, send the entry to a output file and discard. The combination of laziness + discarding last step guarantees that no list is build (actually, I run into several OutOfMemoryErrors, and even a GC Error before I was able to workaround every default strict behavior in the application). If you take a look in the link I posted on @Mike answer, you can follow the entire discussion).

Comment: Anyway, I'm accepting your answer since it was the one that better optimized the Regex :D.

Comment: @Anthony Accioly A scanner has a noticeable higher performance hit than using a BufferedReader and parsing it yourself. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721585/optimizing-my-homework-java-i-o/6721609#6721609) here. Since the format is really simple to parse I'd try one without the RE overhead as a baseline.

Comment: @Voo. Thanks for the suggestion. I understand that I can use `BufferedReader.getLine()`, and, for example, accumulate it on a StringBuilder until I've found the 2 line breaks. Is this what you are suggesting? And after I have each entry what's the suggestion for further parsing?

Comment: @Anthony Accioly Almost - I'd parse it on the go. I found no definite definition for the srt format, but only a forums post. But as I see it your first line is always a sole integer id (that's simply a `parseInt()`), the second is the complex one with time + opt. position and then just read lines until you get an empty line (that's the complete text). Parsing the second line is a bit more complex, but you can split it at the "-->" and use a (cached! don't create a new one each time) SimpleDateFormatter.

Comment: Also note that while you could obviously use a parser generator, the above is really simple to parse (no lookahead necessary for one) so if you're not interested in it for academic reasons, it's not worth the time to learn a whole framework (also it'd probably add a bit overhead depending on what you use). PS: The SimpleDateFormatter string would be something along this lines: `HH:mm:ss:SSS`.

Comment: @Voo. Thank you very much for the suggestions. I guess you are right, line by line imperative like parsing is probably as fast as it gets for such a tasks. I'm using the SimpleDateFormatter (in the above code timeFormat is doing that). I will see how replacing my Scanner with the custom delimiter for a BufferedReader + line by line parsing works out :).

Answer (score 4):

```
(?s)^\d++\s{1,2}(.{12}) --> (.{12})\s{1,2}(.+)\r?$
```

In Java, `$` means the end of input or the beginning of a line-break immediately preceding the end of input.  `\z` means unambiguously end of input, so if that is also the semantics in Scala, then `\r?$` is redundant and `$` would do just as well.  If you really only want a CR at the end and not CRLF then `\r?\z` might be better.

The `(?s)` should also make `(.+)\r?` redundant since the `+` is greedy, the `.` should always expand to include the `\r`.  If you do not want the `\r` included in that third capturing group, then make the match lazy : `(.+?)` instead of `(.+)`.

Maybe

```
(?s)^\d++\s\s?(.{12}) --> (.{12})\s\s?(.+?)\r?\z
```

Other fine high-performance alternatives to regular expressions that will run inside a JVM &| CLR include [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/) and [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).  For a Scala only solution, see http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2008/09/scala-parser-combinators.html

Comment: +1 For mentioning non-regex options, as well as for that excellent link on Scala at the end.

Comment: `++` is valid; it's a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), and if anything he should be using more of them. :D

Comment: Mike, thanks for the suggestion. I tried your regex, but within my flawed microbenchmark it was a tad slower (for 10000 runs, my regex averaged 26.3ms per file, yours 31.4ms. I run the benchmark several times to be sure).
As for Parser Combinators and other compilers tools that builds ASTs, this program may read huge files, so it is more of a read stream -> parse -> dump -> discard cicle. Jim actually was helping me in scala-user lists, and, when I told him about this requirement he also come to the conclusion that parser combinators wouldn't be the best tool for the job.

Comment: @Anthony, Interesting.  In your discussions with Jim, did you discuss "parser combinators" in particular or "parser generators" in general?  ANTLR and friends do a lot of up-front work to reduce a grammar to something efficiently processable by state machine.  Regular expressions can be implemented that way but many are not because they want to support the non-regular behavior of perl5 regexp.  So parser generators can do much better than common regexp libraries for things that have a regular (or CF in the case of ANTLR?) lexical grammar.

Comment: @Alan, thanks for explaining.  If I understand correctly `\d++\s{1,2}` should not be semantically any different than `\d+\s{1,2}` since there is no string in `\d+{1,2}` that has a non-empty suffix that is a non-empty prefix of any string in `\s{1,2}` but obviously only benchmarking would tell for sure whether the qualifier improves things.

Comment: @Mike. We discussed Scala parser combinators in specific. The problem is that the semantic operators (^^ and ^^^) are better intended for building ASTs than to side effect and discard. Someone else stated that it was possible to work around things by writing my own loop combinator or returning Unit (scala's sort of equivalent to "Void" type) to improve memory usage, but anyway, the general feeling is that for what I wanted to do loop(read->process->output->discard) It would require ugly workarounds.

Comment: Anyway, I will give a deep dive into compilers tools. I feel like I missed a lot for not taking the compilers course in college... Those are really useful tools. Guess learning Scala is the start of a huge journey to reeducate myself :D.

Comment: Just to clear something up. I just read the e-mails in Scala list and the one that was trying to educate me about combinator parsers was Eugen Labun. Jim McBeth was the one making an huge effort to teach me about lazy and strict evaluation... :D (hard stuff for OO / imperative guys like me). Here is the link for further reference: [IO and parsing with idiomatic style?](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-user/browse_thread/thread/d9f93b69c9e62d00).

Comment: @Mike: Another advantage of using possessive quantifiers and atomic groups is that it frees the regex engine from having to save the state information that makes backtracking possible.  It may be obvious *to us* that backtracking into something like `\s\d+\s` is pointless, but NFA regex engines like Java's (and .NET's, and Python's, and Perl's...) tend to prepare for it anyway, unless we tell them not to.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
(?m)^\d++\r?+\n(.{12}) --> (.{12})\r?+\n(.++(?>\r?+\n.++)*+)$
```

This regex matches a complete .srt file entry *in place*.  You don't have to split the contents up on line breaks first; that's a huge waste of resources.

The regex takes advantage of the fact that there's exactly one line separator (`\n` or `\r\n`) separating the lines within an entry (multiple line separators are used to separate entries from each other).  Using `\r?+\n` instead of `\s{1,2}` means you can never accidentally match two line separators (`\n\n`) when you only wanted to match one.

This way, too, you don't have to rely on the `.` in `(?s)` mode.  @Jacob was right about that: it's not really helping you, and it's killing your performance.  But `(?m)` mode *is* helpful, for correctness as well as performance.

You mentioned `java.util.Scanner`; this regex would work very nicely with `findWithinHorizon(0)`.  But I'd be surprised if Scala doesn't offer a nice, idiomatic way to use it as well.

Comment: Alan, thank you very much for the alternative solution. I forget to mention in my original question that I don't really need to read the entire file at once. An also, I do need the times.Still, I'm up voting because of the mad regex skills with the nested non capturing group inside the capturing group. That is the kind of stuff that tells apart regex wizards from the rest of us :D.

Comment: You mean you need to capture the `.{12}` parts, representing times?  I didn't drop those parens purposefully, I was just concentrating on performance rather than side effects. I added them back in.  And if you're only applying the regex to individual entries, I can't see performance being that big a deal--but I would avoid `DOTALL` mode anyway.

Comment: Alan, I think I didn't express myself well. My Application spends more than 70% of its time within this method, that's why I'm focusing on it. The reason I don't read the entire file at once is because It may be huge (gigabytes), so I'm just reading a Entry at a time, parsing, processing, writing to the output and discarding.

Comment: But the method does more than just regex matching.  How much time is it spending in those two calls to `timeFormat.parse()`?

Comment: Less time than what it appears. Good, old and verbose `java.util.Scanner` will practically halve the time (and the parse methods are still used)... But I guess that's how regex works. Succinctness for a tad of performance. Seems fair.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `java.util.Scanner` or even strings.  Everything you're doing will work perfectly on a byte stream as long as you can assume UTF-8 encoding of your files (or a lack of unicode).  You should be able to speed things up by at least 5x.

---

Edit: this is just a lot of low-level fiddling of bytes and indices.  Here's something based loosely on things I've done before, which seems about 2x-5x faster, depending on file size, caching, etc..  I'm not doing the date parsing here, just returning strings, and I'm assuming the files are small enough to fit in a single block of memory (i.e. <2G).  This is being rather pedantically careful; if you know, for example, that the date string format is always okay, then the parsing can be faster yet (just count the characters after the first line of digits).

```
import java.io._
abstract class Entry {
  def isDefined: Boolean
  def date1: String
  def date2: String
  def text: String
}
case class ValidEntry(date1: String, date2: String, text: String) extends Entry {
  def isDefined = true
}
object NoEntry extends Entry {
  def isDefined = false
  def date1 = ""
  def date2 = ""
  def text = ""
}

final class Seeker(f: File) {
  private val buffer = {
    val buf = new Array[Byte](f.length.toInt)
    val fis = new FileInputStream(f)
    fis.read(buf)
    fis.close()
    buf
  }
  private var i = 0
  private var d1,d2 = 0
  private var txt,n = 0
  def isDig(b: Byte) = ('0':Byte) <= b && ('9':Byte) >= b
  def nextNL() {
    while (i < buffer.length && buffer(i) != '\n') i += 1
    i += 1
    if (i < buffer.length && buffer(i) == '\r') i += 1
  }
  def digits() = {
    val zero = i
    while (i < buffer.length && isDig(buffer(i))) i += 1
    if (i==zero || i >= buffer.length || buffer(i) != '\n') {
      nextNL()
      false
    }
    else {
      nextNL()
      true
    }
  }
  def dates(): Boolean = {
    if (i+30 >= buffer.length) {
      i = buffer.length
      false
    }
    else {
      d1 = i
      while (i < d1+12 && buffer(i) != '\n') i += 1
      if (i < d1+12 || buffer(i)!=' ' || buffer(i+1)!='-' || buffer(i+2)!='-' || buffer(i+3)!='>' || buffer(i+4)!=' ') {
        nextNL()
        false
      }
      else {
        i += 5
        d2 = i
        while (i < d2+12 && buffer(i) != '\n') i += 1
        if (i < d2+12 || buffer(i) != '\n') {
          nextNL()
          false
        }
        else {
          nextNL()
          true
        }
      }
    }
  }
  def gatherText() {
    txt = i
    while (i < buffer.length && buffer(i) != '\n') {
      i += 1
      nextNL()
    }
    n = i-txt
    nextNL()
  }
  def getNext: Entry = {
    while (i < buffer.length) {
      if (digits()) {
        if (dates()) {
          gatherText()
          return ValidEntry(new String(buffer,d1,12), new String(buffer,d2,12), new String(buffer,txt,n))
        }
      }
    }
    return NoEntry
  }
}
```

Now that you see that, aren't you glad that the regex solution was so quick to code?

Comment: thank your very much, but I'm really lost about "parsing" from a Byte Stream... Would you mind sharing some code?

Comment: Wow. That's some really low level parsing :).
But indeed, I guess this is the kind of situation where optimization means going raw. For learning purposes I will try to go this deep. Just a quick question, to avoid loading the entire file at once, I was thinking about using a BufferedStream (say 100k buffer) and make every method already return Option[Type] it it finds the input, None it it didn't. Wold I achieve similar performance with this strategy?

Comment: @Anthony Accioly - You'll lose a bit of performance by generating a bunch of `Option` instances, but it should still work reasonably well.  Just be careful to always store your bytes in arrays of bytes and access them directly, not via handy Scala collections methods.  Those require boxing, and will therefore give a sizable performance hit.